# How do I stop footnotes becoming links when I use hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

I am using `hyperref` in `LaTeX` for references. When I have references in footnotes, the entire footnote becomes a link. How do I fix this?

I tried to create an MWE, however this is eliminated the problem somehow!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with the hyperref option `hyperfootnotes=false`?